# Magento - Custom Value on Create Shipment page

Tags: php, magento

We have a custom field in the sales_flat_order_item table called "column1".  We use this field to hold what we call "picked" values.

Our process per order line is basically Ordered > Invoiced > Picked > Shipped.  What we'd like is to only be able to ship "picked" items.  On the create shipment page, I've added the picked value like so:

[image: Picked value on shipment screen]

Using the example above, we can see that 1 of the teabags was ordered and 0 are picked.  I'd therefore like the "Qty to Ship" value to be 0 rather than 1.

Inside /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/items.phtml I can see that the following lines create the "Qty to Ship" field:

```
<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
<?php echo $this->getItemExtraInfoHtml($_item->getOrderItem()) ?>
```

How can I get this to read from our custom "column1" field instead?

Thanks! If you need more information let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now found where this can be done and got it working.

The file you need to change is actually this one:

/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/items/renderer

Line 34 contains the code for the input box.  The "value" can be changed here.